# Draw figures in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am building an application where I have to draw my own figures on a Canvas. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
PathFigure figure = new PathFigure() { StartPoint = new Point(0, TurboHeight / turboSizeFactor * turboSchaufelFactor), IsClosed = true};
LineSegment seg = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(turboWidth, TurboHeight / turboSizeFactor * turboSchaufelFactor) };
figure.Segments.Add(seg);
seg = new LineSegment(){Point=new Point(turboWidth*0.85, 0)};
figure.Segments.Add(seg);
seg = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(turboWidth * 0.15, 0) };
figure.Segments.Add(seg);
PathGeometry geo = new PathGeometry();
geo.Figures.Add(figure);
Path path = new Path() { Data = geo, Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 1, SnapsToDevicePixels = true, Fill = Brushes.LightGray};
CnvMain.Children.Add(path);
```

Is this the way to do it or is there a simpler way. I mean its a lot of objects I am creating for a few lines on a canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: You may look into [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx). It is a light-weight alternative to PathGeometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you're not wasting too much. Only thing I would do is not store all the intermediate results in variables that you reuse... E.g.:

```
PathFigure figure = new PathFigure() 
{ 
    StartPoint = new Point(0, TurboHeight / turboSizeFactor * turboSchaufelFactor),
    IsClosed = true
};


figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(turboWidth, TurboHeight / turboSizeFactor * turboSchaufelFactor) });
figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(turboWidth * 0.85, 0) });
figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(turboWidth * 0.15, 0) });

PathGeometry geo = new PathGeometry();
geo.Figures.Add(figure);

Path path = new Path() { Data = geo, Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 1, SnapsToDevicePixels = true, Fill = Brushes.LightGray };

CnvMain.Children.Add(path);
```

You could of course put the whole stuff in a method or put the points in an array, but for such a small function that seems just silly... if you have more points it might make sense.